# How to efficiently forward request to multiple endpoints using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest

I built a nodejs server to act as an adapter server, which upon receiving a post request containing some data, extracts the data from the request body and then forwards it to a few other external servers. Finally, my server will send a response consisting of the responses from each of the external server (success/fail).

If there's only 1 endpoint to forward to, it seems fairly straightforward. However, when I have to forward to more than one servers, I have to rely on things like Promise.All(), which has a fail-fast behaviour. That means if one promise is rejected (an external server is down), all other promises will also be rejected immediately and the rest the servers will not receive my data.

Comment: You're asking a somewhat generic question, but the only answer involves coding a specific solution to a specific problem.  If you don't want fast fail with `Promise.all()`, then you need to describe what you do want and explain EXACTLY what you're trying to accomplish so someone can help you code that.  As your question is written now, there is no generic way to answer it and it should probably just be closed.

Comment: `Promise.all()` works the way it does because it's the most common design case.  If you have a different design objective in mind and you want us to help you code it, you'd have to share what your design objective is (probably with actual code to see).

Comment: Also see [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Actually `Promise.all()` does not mean that the other servers will not receive your data.  One would typically use `Promise.all()` when you've already sent all the requests to all the other servers and you are waiting to be notified when they are done or fail.  So, even if one fails, all the requests have been sent.  `Promise.all()` just won't tell you which one's succeeded or failed as it only notifies you when the first one fails or if they all succeed.  They've all been sent.

Answer (score 5):

May be this ain't be the exact solution. But, what I am posting could be the work around of your problem.

Few days back I had the same problem, as I wanted to implement API versioning. Here is the solution I implemented, please have a look.

[Architecture Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNHpt.jpg)

Let me explain this diagram

Here in the diagram is the initial configuration for the server as we do. all the api request come here will pass to the "index.js" file inside the release directory.

index.js (in release directory)

```
const express = require('express');

const fid = require('./core/file.helper');

const router = express.Router();

fid.getFiles(__dirname,'./release').then(releases => {
    releases.forEach(release => {
        // release = release.replace(/.js/g,''); 
        router.use(`/${release}`,require(`./release/${release}/index`))
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

code snippet for helper.js

```
//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    getFiles: (presentDirectory, directoryName) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //joining path of directory 
            const directoryPath = path.join(presentDirectory, directoryName);
            //passsing directoryPath and callback function

            fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {

                // console.log(files);

                //handling error
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
                    reject(err)
                }
                //listing all files using forEach
                // files.forEach(function (file) {
                //     // Do whatever you want to do with the file
                //     console.log(file); 
                // });
                resolve(files)
            });
        })


    }
}
```

Now, from this index file all the index.js inside each version folder is mapped

Here is the code bellow for "index.js" inside v1 or v2 ...

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fid = require('../../core/file.helper');
const dbconf = require('./config/datastore');
const router = express.Router();

// const connection_string = `mongodb+srv://${dbconf.atlas.username}:${dbconf.atlas.password}@${dbconf.atlas.host}/${dbconf.atlas.database}`;
const connection_string = `mongodb://${dbconf.default.username}:${dbconf.default.password}@${dbconf.default.host}:${dbconf.default.port}/${dbconf.default.database}`;

mongoose.connect(connection_string,{
    useCreateIndex: true,    
    useNewUrlParser:true
}).then(status => {

    console.log(`Database connected to mongodb://${dbconf.atlas.username}@${dbconf.atlas.host}/${dbconf.atlas.database}`);

    fid.getFiles(__dirname,'./endpoints').then(files => {

        files.forEach(file => {
            file = file.replace(/.js/g,''); 
            router.use(`/${file}`,require(`./endpoints/${file}`))
        });

    })

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error connecting database ${err}`);
})

module.exports = router
```

In each of this index.js inside version folder is actually mapped to each endpoints inside endpoints folder.

code for one of the endpoints is given bellow

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const userCtrl = require('../controllers/users');


router.post('/signup', userCtrl.signup);
router.post('/login', userCtrl.login);

module.exports = router;
```

Here in this file actually we are connecting the endpoints to its controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {'targets':
            [
                'https://abc.api.xxx',
                'https://xyz.abc',
                'https://stackoverflow.net'
            ]};
relay(req, resp, config);               
function relay(req, resp, config) {
    doRelay(req, resp, config['targets'], relayOne);
}

function doRelay(req, resp, servers, relayOne) {
    var finalresponses = [];
    if (servers.length > 0) {
        var loop = function(servers, index, relayOne, done) {
            relayOne(req, servers[index], function(response) {
                finalresponses.push[response];
                if (++index < servers.length) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        loop(servers, index, relayOne, done);
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    done(resp, finalresponses);
                }
            });
        };
        loop(servers, 0, relayOne, done);
    } else {
        done(resp, finalresponses);
    }
}

function relayOne(req, targetserver, relaydone) {
//call the targetserver and return the response data
/*return relaydone(response data);*/
}

function done(resp, finalresponses){
    console.log('ended');
    resp.writeHead(200, 'OK', {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
    });
    resp.end(finalresponses);
    return;
}
```

Comment: this should help on what you are looking for. Just sample code snippet I pasted. If you need more help fell free to ping me

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to design a *reverse proxy*. If you are struggling to get custom code to work, there is a free npm library which is very robust.

I would recommend node-http-proxy

I have posted link below, which will lead you directly to the "modify response", since you mentioned modification of the API format in your question. Be sure to read the entire page though.

https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#modify-a-response-from-a-proxied-server

Note: this library is also very good because it can support SSL, and proxies to both localhost (servers on the same machine) and servers on other machines (remote).

Comment: It sounds like the OP needs to contact multiple external servers in order to synthesize a response to an incoming API call.  That is not something an out-of-the-box proxy knows how to do.

Comment: I see the problem now. But it is not exactly clear from the question that that is true. Perhaps OP should edit their question?

Comment: Yes, which is why I've left multiple comments to the original question rather than guessing with an answer and am waiting for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Okay, I have learned something about stack overflow etiquette today. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. I edited the question. Hopefully, it is clearer now...

Answer (score -1):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) from MDN

> It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

To overcome the problem, you'll need to `catch()` each request you've made.
e.g.

```
Promise.all([
    request('<url 1>').catch(err => /* .. error handling */),
    request('<url 2>').catch(err => /* .. error handling */),
    request('<url 3>').catch(err => /* .. error handling */)
])
.then(([result1, result2, result3]) => {

    if(result1.err) { }

    if(result2.err) { }

    if(result3.err) { }

})
```